# how to get the emitter position of an animated CAEmitterLayer/Cell?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, caemitterlayer

I have a animated CAEmitterLayer with CAEmitterCell and the animation runs well with

```
 fireEmitter = (CAEmitterLayer*)self.layer; 
    fireEmitter.emitterPosition = CGPointMake(50, 50);
    fireEmitter.emitterSize = CGSizeMake(10, 10);

    CAEmitterCell* fire = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
    ...
    [fire setName:@"fire"];

CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"emitterPosition"];
    anim.path = theBezierPath.CGPath;
    anim.calculationMode = kCAAnimationCubicPaced;
    anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    anim.duration = 12.0;
    [self.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"fire"];
```

my bezier path is closed and forms a "8" out of four position points.
with my timerFunction I try to get the position of the CAEmitterLayer every second. for that I use

```
-(CGPoint)getEmitterPosition
{
    return fireEmitter.emitterPosition;
}
```

in the emitter class and

```
CGPoint emitterPosition = [self.ParticleEmitterView getEmitterPosition];
NSLog(@"%f / %f", emitterPosition.y, emitterPosition.y);
```

from the timer function.

But when the animation is running the console spits out the same positio every call allthough the emitter is running over the screen.

why is that and how could I get the emitter position of an animated CAEmitterLayer/Cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried querying the `CAEmitterLayer`'s `presentationLayer` property and asking the resulting `CALayer` for its position? The presentation layer should give you access to the properties of the layer as they appear on the screen during the animation, while the emitter layer will give you the properties as they will be at the end of all current animations.

This is due to the model-view separation inherent in [Core Animation's rendering architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/CoreAnimationArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006655-SW1).

Comment: sounds promissing. thank you. I try to understand and use that - as new as I am to objective-c... by the way: when I change the emitter position with touchesMoved and `-(void)setEmitterPositionToPoint: (CGPoint)p
{
    //change the emitter's position
    fireEmitter.emitterPosition = p;
}` everything works fine and I get the right position traced out.

Comment: I would expect that. You'll want to keep setting properties directly on your emitter layer; it's just that the presentation layer gives you a way to read back properties as they actually appear during animations.

Comment: I now tried to return the position of the representationLayer via `CALayer *fireEmitterLayer = fireEmitter.presentationLayer;
    return fireEmitterLayer.position;` but the problem is still the same.

Comment: hm - it could'nt be impossible to track the position of animated layers, right?

Comment: maybe it's because of the initialization: `fireEmitter = (CAEmitterLayer*)self.layer;`?

Comment: the main differences I see is that I overwrite the layerClass:`+ (Class) layerClass 
{
    //configure the UIView to have emitter layer
    return [CAEmitterLayer class];
}` and init with `fireEmitter = (CAEmitterLayer*)self.layer;`

Comment: or maybe the problem is that I create the emitter from inside the view, not the viewController?

Comment: I changed some settings and now it works fine! thank you for your demo code. that helped a lot!

Comment: unfortunately this change of code broke some other funktionality of my app... :-(

Comment: could you bring your code together with the 'draw with fire' functionality to follow the touch input data - stopping the path animation when touched first time, then following the fingers touch?

Comment: the problem now is that the particle trail is way beyond the touch position, looks like it is delayed by something.

Comment: opened a new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930668/touches-moved-caemitterlayer-delayed-in-dinstance-after-touch-point